# SQL Server IN (maximum,params,allowed,in,here)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How many params can I pass to SQL Servers IN() function?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where ID IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,..,.,....)
```

Comment: probably more than you would reasonably need. have you seen `BETWEEN`?

Comment: there is no chance in using BETWEEN (got just single IDs, no particular ranges). But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) - "many thousands".

Comment: The documentation says *not* to use "many thousands" as that can cause an exception :)

Comment: If "many thousands" could cause an error, "many thousands - 1" should be fine, and since "many thousands - 1" is almost always still "many thousands", query should work fine with "many thousands" values :-)

Answer (score 8):

This limit is **65,535**.

Refer the Causes section [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913050).

Answer (score 6):

Including an extremely large number of values (many thousands) in an `IN clause` can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632. To work around this problem, store the items in the IN list in a table.

> **Error 8623:**
>
> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.
>
> **Error 8632:**
>
> Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please
>   look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to
>   simplify them.